# Wordpress giving me a 404 error for php form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email

Since the Wordpress form seems to not want to send me the password to my account for help on their forums I figured I would start here.

I have created a form for my website so that someone can contact us.

But when the person clicks the 'send' button it takes them to a 404 page, which the address reads:

website address - /working/mail.php

I know Wordpress supports .php files and I have mine correctly named and wasn't sure if I am missing something

```
    <div id="FGSform"> 
   <form action="mail.php" method="post" name="contactFGS" id="contactFGS">
<ul>
<li>
    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
<br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required aria-required="true">
</li>
<br>
<li>
    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required aria-required="true">
</li>
<br>
<li>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
<br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required aria-required="true">
</li>
<br>
<li>
  <label for="contact-reason" id="reason" name="reason">Reason for Contact</label>
      <select required id="reason" name="reason">
      <option value="3">Employment</option>
      <option value="1">Print Services</option>
      <option value="2">Design Services</option>
      <option value="4">Questions</option>
      <option value="5">Other</option>
    </select> 
</li>
<br>
<li>
  <label for="comments">Comments</label>
<br>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="40" rows="10" required></textarea>
</li> 
<br>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
    <label for="signmeup">Sign me up for newsletter, updates and other information about FGS</label>  
</li>
<br>
<li>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</li>
```

Here is my .php file:

```
<?php

 /* Email Variables */
 $emailSubject = 'mail!'; 
$webMaster = 'kmurray.1@frgraphicsolutions.com';



/* Data Variables */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = $_POST['email'];





$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Last Name: $lastname <br>
Email: $email <br>
Comments: $comments <br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);


/* Results rendered as HTML */
$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>sent message</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://frgraphicsolutions.com/working/?page_id=8">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-color: #444; 
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fec001;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 200px;
margin-left: 150px;
width: 800px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<div align="center">Thank you!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

I have never created a form before, but Wordpress plug-ins are terrible designed and/or over complicate the form giving me little control over what I want in it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you replace the contents of your mail.php file with a 1 line "Hello World" PHP file, do you still get a 404? If yes, it's an issue with where/how you're uploading your file. If no, it's an issue with the HTTP response header code in mail.php .

Comment: Check to see if your `mail.php` file actually exists, since that's what the form handler is looking for. If it does not reside in the same folder as your form, then that could produce a 404 error. Also, some servers treat `mail.php` and `Mail.php` differently. Try using as your form action `<form action="/working/mail.php"`

Comment: Try putting your entire code (Form/PHP) in one file, then use this as your action `<form action=""` and tell me if you get any results.

Comment: @user2701059 Your code works and checks out. You obviously either did not properly name your form handler's action, or the `mail.php` file does not exist and/or you didn't upload it. That's my take on it.

Comment: Set your your form action to this then `<form action="/working/wp-content/themes/NEW/mail.php"` and you should be getting mail now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### After time spent with the OP to find out what the problem was, have determined the following solution:

Set your your form action to this

```
<form action="/working/wp-content/themes/NEW/mail.php" method="post" name="contactFGS" id="contactFGS">
```

Since the `mail.php` file (handler) was inside a themes folder, and not as previously thought.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot post comments yet or I would add this as a comment but it seems there is no `mail.php` file. Can you check the full path to the file? It's not in `/` or in `/working/`.

**Edit** in response to your comment:

You should try two things in that order:

1. Output the result of the form just to check that you are reaching
   the form processing file and that everything is working on that
   side.
2. Send an email to yourself using basic parameters, in a file with no
   link with the form. This way you'll know if you are able to send
   emails properly and you'll be closer to a solution.

Let us know what you find.

Comment: I think the link was incorrect as you said. I corrected it, but now it seems like I am not getting the email?

Answer (score 0):

Change the path in the form tag to /mail.php or whatever is the url of mail.php

EDIT:

Incase it's not clear, just change the form action to the url of your mail.php..